# 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on this server

Tags: plugins, htaccess, permissions, user-access, backup

When I try to make a backup of my wordpress website through plugin I recieve the following error:

"403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on this server."

This error also appears sometimes during installation of plugins.

My htaccess file:

```
# Begin Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Structure of Server:

```
-/
  -/wordpress
  -/oldfiles
  -/other
```

inside /wordpress my entire wordpress website exists as:

```
-/wordpress
 -/wp-admin
 -/wp-content
 -/.htaccess
```

etc etc.....

**Things I've tried:**

-Used different plugins for backup (1 Updraft, 2 Duplicator) both show the same error.

-Change file permissions from ftp client.

Set 755 permission to wp-admin, wp-includes, wp-content directories

Set 644 to all files inside the directories and 755 to all the sub-folders.

**-I even changed the folder permission of /wp-admin to 755 and admin-ajax.php to 777 but still getting the same error**

-Made modification in .htaccess file as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<Files admin-ajax.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

-Disabled all plugins and enabled only the backup creating plugins, same error.

-Deleted .htaccess file

-Made a temporary 301 redirect in .htaccess file to be sure I was working on the right .htaccess file

-Disabled "Wordfence security" plugin

Comment: Whilst your WordPress installation appears to be in the `/wordpress` subdirectory, the WordPress `.htaccess` file appears to load `/index.php` in the document root? The error msg that you stated also references `/wp-admin/....` in the document root?

Comment: There's a default redirect set to go to /wordpress sub-directory. The .htaccess file is inside the /wordpress sub-directory. Besides, I also set permissions of 755 on the /wp-admin inside the subdirectory and 644 to the admin-ajax.php still nothing happened.

Comment: What happens when you request `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` (or `/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`) directly? What about the file's "group"? I would check if there are any Apache security modules that might be interfering: mod_security, mod_evasive, etc.?

Comment: _Aside:_ "a default redirect" - I assume by that you mean there is an _internal rewrite_ in a parent `.htaccess` file that rewrites the request directly to `/wordpress/index.php`? That maybe so, but it doesn't make the `/wordpress/.htaccess` file correct - either there would seem to be an additional / unnecessary rewrite going on here or the front-controller in `/wordpress/.htaccess` is being bypassed? (Would need to see the parent `.htaccess` file to know for sure how your WP URLs are being routed.) Although this is unlikely to have anything to do with your "permissions" issue.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it's probably caused by mod-evasive (or similar) plugin in Apache (or similar), blocking multiple consecutive requests as it thinks you are trying to run a denial of service (DOS) attack against the server. Try disabling any security plugins (Apache / web server ones, not WordPr